# Append files output dynamically

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I'm trying to append the contents of several files into a single combined one. Right now I'm doing it like this:

```
cat file1 >> file2 >> file3 >> combined
```

It is working fine, but the issue is I want to replicate this behavior dynamically for every file in a directory. I tried this approach:

```
for f in *; do
  cat "$f" >> combined
done
```

But it doesn't seem to be working as intended.

Comment: Your first line is not "working fine". Shell does all redirections before starting the command. This opens file2 and file3 for append, and immediately closes them, because of the next redirection. It then appends *only* file1 to combined. Your new approach fails because the list from `*` includes `combined`, and `cat` is smart enough to avoid writing a file over itself.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant, it seems to work for me with GNU tools, exactly because `cat` _is_ smart enough to not go in an unbounded loop there. It won't work with e.g. Busybox, which _isn't_ smart enough, though.

Comment: @ilkkachu  OP said "doesn't seem to be working as intended" which is fairly unhelpful. Choice of errors: (a) cat throws *cat: qqq: input file is output file*; (b) cat endlessly appends file to itself. Weirdly, `cat qqq >> qqq` does *not* object if qqq is empty -- I guess it short-circuits that with a `stat`. Nor does the `>>` append update the modify time in that case, even though bash opened the file for appending. I like `cat * | sponge -a combined` here.

Answer (score 0):

The loop you had there:

> ```
> for f in *; do
>   cat "$f" >> combined
> done
> ```

should be fine if the file `combined` doesn't exist beforehand, so it will not be included in the list produced by the `*` (it also assumes file names don't start with `-`).

If it does exist, the loop will eventually run `cat combined >> combined`, which will append the contents of the file to the same file until the system runs out of space or the program is interrupted. Except if you run the GNU version of cat, where that will just produce an error: *"cat: combined: input file is output file"*.

To avoid that, you could explicitly check that `$f` isn't `combined`:

```
for f in *; do
    if [ "$f" != combined ]; then
        cat < "$f" >> combined
    fi
done
```

or use a glob pattern that excludes `combined` (in Bash):

```
shopt -s extglob
for f in !(combined); do
  cat < "$f" >> combined
done
```

in which case you might as well forgo the loop and give `cat` the list of filenames all at once:

```
cat ./!(combined) >> combined
```

(`!(combined)` should work in ksh also (where that syntax comes from). In zsh, the corresponding syntax would be `set -o extendedglob; cat ./^combined >> combined`, preferred over the ksh syntax, also supported there after `set -o kshglob`).